# Does append mode in spark with orc as the storage sort the orc file?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, orc

From my understanding orc filter is extremely fast because both file and stripe have

> column-level aggregates count, min, max, and sum

However it would seem like those meta data is useful only if the column is sorted?
If its not sorted, then those meta data doesn't seem to be very useful because each file and stripe would have large range of min and max

If thats the case, what happens when you are in append mode when you append your dataframe to existing orc file destination (list of orc files)?

Does it sort the entire orc file list and write those file again, if so whats the difference between append mode and non append mode?

```
dataframe.write.mode("append").format("orc").save("mydata.orc")
```

Answer (score 1):

> If thats the case, what happens when you are in append mode when you append your dataframe to existing orc file?

Actually, it will create another orc file in your destination folder. For e.g: when you first write your data, it will look like:

```bash
mydata.orc
├── part-00000-a4b69ad6-feab-4323-bb9b-428ff492f222-c000.snappy.orc
└── _SUCCESS
```

When you append new data, it will create new orc file:

```bash
mydata.orc
├── part-00000-8ccb22e5-2c36-456b-93e0-087b4edf4b33-c000.snappy.orc
├── part-00000-a4b69ad6-feab-4323-bb9b-428ff492f222-c000.snappy.orc
└── _SUCCESS
```

ORC has columnar file format, which is unable to append by inserting lines at the end of the file. Also, when spark write to orc, it will create a folder of orc files, instead of writing only 1 file.

> Does it sort the entire orc file and write the file again, if so whats the difference between append mode and non append mode?

Apparently no. If you want to sort and write it again, that will be `override` mode in spark. In this mode, all your existed data will be cleared before writing new one.

Other save modes are: `errorifexists` and `ignore`. Both will not update your data, but `errorifexists` will throw an error instead.